# Youtube Parsing Json in android

Tags: android, json, youtube

I'm trying to create a request to youtube and trying to parse the json-c
it's work for this :

> http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/RadioIfm/playlists?&max-results=50&v=2&alt=jsonc

but when I traied to get a videos by Playlist_Id with this link :

> http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLFApv2COP4eq9pnSqtSV_1GpkvFE0EWi6?v=2&alt=jsonc

it doesn't work and this is my code to parse JSON:

```
public void getData()
{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);


    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLFApv2COP4eq9pnSqtSV_1GpkvFE0EWi6?v=2&alt=jsonc");     


    try
    {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
    String _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); 

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(_response);

    JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("items");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        String title1 = jsonObject.getString("title");
        title.add(title1);
        String thumbUrl = jsonObject.getJSONObject("thumbnail").getString("sqDefault");
        URL url1 = new URL(thumbUrl);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url1.openConnection().getInputStream());
        thumb.add(bmp);
        String url;
        try {

            url = jsonObject.getJSONObject("player").getString("default");
            msg.add(url);
        } catch (Exception ignore) {

       }
    }
    } 
    catch(Exception e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Paste code error pless.

Comment: no code error  
it works for the 1st link but i got nothing with the 2nd link

Comment: @OussamaJebali have a look at my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31113192/how-to-get-youtube-gdata-playlist-json-response