# How to get Youtube GData Playlist JSON response

Tags: android, json, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I have to parse this youtube playlist into my app using gdata: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9ofd2f-_-xmUi07wIGZa1c

So I think, I should need to use below link to get JSON response: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLWz5rJ2EKKc9ofd2f-_-xmUi07wIGZa1c?v=2&alt=jsonc

But whenever i am opening it on browser, every time getting:

`{"apiVersion":"2.1","error":{"code":410,"message":"No longer available","errors":[{"domain":"GData","code":"NoLongerAvailableException","internalReason":"No longer available"}]}}`

I have tried with latest version (i.e - 3):

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLWz5rJ2EKKc9ofd2f-_-xmUi07wIGZa1c?v=3&alt=jsonc
```

and getting: `{"error":{"code":403,"message":"Version 3 is not supported.","errors":[{"domain":"GData","code":"versionNotSupported","internalReason":"Version 3 is not supported."}]}}`

**So how may i get gdata json response ?** to parse later in my android app

Comment: yes it's Json Response to check it's valid Json or not use online Json View http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: i don't want to validate my JSON, i am looking for the JSON response which we get from youtube gdata to parse

Comment: That call is to v2 of the API which is deprecated and no longer available. If you want to get the videos associated with a playlist you can use the PlaylistItems:List call. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list

Answer (score 1):

the api you work with is no more available try the new Youtube API

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/